# Android: directions files not generating

Tags: android

[problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49qJE.png)

Last week I had a lot of problems with Android Studio, today I have one more

What can be the problem, why developers of android studio not checking what are they sending in their updates?

now I am forbidden to write new questions, they say that old ones need to be corrected, well, there are no unanswered questions, what should I do?
!¡!

Comment: ok , i am ready to provide more code, what code do you need?

Comment: One moment, I will try

Comment: e: /Users/qweasdzxc/Desktop/MyCarNormal/app/src/main/java/com/mycar/ui/auto/AutoFragment.kt: (31, 23): Unresolved reference: PagerFragmentDirections

Comment: that's the point

Comment: all "directions" are now not generating

Comment: Added a bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158603744

Comment: Fixed: now using destinations via resources (R)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What can I say: it's been a long time since I've been working with the navigation component. Directions may not be formed immediately, but after several assemblies.